# How to access public method present inside private class

Tags: java, android

My Code:

```
public class location
{

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
       //Get the Signal strength from the provider, each time there is an update 
      @Override
      public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
      {

      }
/*some text*/

}
```

how can i invoke "onSignalStrengthsChanged" method from "location" class.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new `MyPhoneStateListener` instance and invoke the method on this instance.

For example:

```
public class location {

    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
      //Get the Signal strength from the provider, each time there is an update 
      @Override
      public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
      {

      }
      /*some text*/

    }

    public void doSomething() {
        PhoneStateListener listener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        listener.onSignalStrenghtsChanged(...);
    }
}
```

Please notice that you can only create a `MyPhoneStateListener` instance in the `location` class because you defined the class private.

Also, notice that `doSomething()` belongs to `location`.